# Replace substrings using a reference table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to replace substrings within one text column in my table using a reference table.
To my knowledge, the replace(column, string1,string2) function will only work with strings as the second and third input.

Here is a visual of what I am trying to do. To be clear, the reference table I need to use is much larger - otherwise, I would use four replace functions.

EDIT: Thank you to everyone who has pointed out how bad this data model is built. Though I am not an expert on building efficient data models, I do know this one is built terribly. However, the structure of this model is completely out of my control. Apologies for not mentioning that from the get-go.

```
  table1
```

| Farms | Animals |
| --- | --- |
| Farm1 | Cow, Pig |
| Farm2 | Dog, Cow, Cat |
| Farm3 | Dog |

```
referenceTable
```

| refColumn1 | refColumn2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cow | Moo |
| Pig | Oink |
| Dog | Bark |
| Cat | Meow |

And here is what I would like the result column to be..

```
  table1
```

| Farms | Animals |
| --- | --- |
| Farm1 | Moo, Oink |
| Farm2 | Bark, Moo, Meow |
| Farm3 | Bark |

First question on stackoverflow so apologies if I missed anything.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it only works with strings, but those strings can come from a table column.

Comment: You can get the `REPLACE()` parameters from `referenceTable`, but I'm not sure you can combine all the replacements of an input row into a single row in the result.

Comment: You'll have to iterate through your substrings (animals). In SQL you'd typically use a recursive query for this. The data model is horrible by the way. If you are interested in the separate animals, then store them separately.

Comment: To address the horrible data model. Sorry, it did not accurately represent the purpose of the data. There are reasons for grouping the animals and I have updated the table to show this.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  how many animals will a table1 row at most have?

Comment: The data model/schema is _BROKEN_. It's **never** a good idea to store comma-separated values in a single column.

Comment: There can be reasons to do things in nonstandard ways, but I can think of multiple ways off the top of my head where storing the data like this and trying to manipulate it like you are doing could go wrong - either performance hits or in some cases making it impossible to achieve your goal - and I can't think of a case where it would help to store it like this. Perhaps you could expand on why you feel breaking normal structure is called for. One problem with this approach, btw, is partial matches, so you will need to be absolutely sure those don't happen in your real data.

Comment: while you can have reasons for grouping the animals, that doesn't make it any less horrible; it just means you have reasons to do something horrible :)

Comment: @ysth 5.7.12 and it looks to be 35 maximum values.

Answer (score 0):

To loop over comma (or ', ' in this case) separated values, you can use a double substring_index and a join against a sequence table (where the sequence is <= the number of joined values in a given row, as determined with char_length/replace):

```
select t1.Farms, group_concat(rt.refColumn2 order by which.n separator ', ') Animals
from table1 t1
join (select 1 n union select 2 union select 3) which
    on ((char_length(t1.Animals)-char_length(replace(t1.Animals,', ','')))/char_length(', '))+1 >= which.n
join referenceTable rt on rt.refColumn1=substring_index(substring_index(t1.Animals,', ',which.n),', ',-1)
group by t1.Farms
```

Here I use an ad hoc sequence table of 1 through 3, assuming no row will have more than 3 animals; expand as necessary or alternatively use a cte.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like there is a max of 35 values in one row (I know, the data model sucks but it's not in my control) but it looks doable and worth creating when I have dynamic values!

Answer (score 0):

You have a really lousy data model and you should fix it.  You should not be storing multiple values in a string column.  Each value pair should be on its own row.

Let me assume that someone else created these tables and you have no choice.  If that is the case, MySQL has a solution.  I think I would suggest:

```
select t1.*,   -- or whatever columns you want
       (select group_concat(rt.refColumn2
                            order by find_in_set(rt.refColumn1, replace(t1.animals, ', ', ',')) 
                            separator ', '
                           )
        from referenceTable rt
        where find_in_set(rt.refColumn1, replace(t1.animals, ', ', ',')) > 0
       )
from table1 t1
```

Comment: to confirm your assumption - Yes. I have no control over this data model. The data is being migrated and the source data extract is in this format. 
Anyway, thank you for this! I think that should work!

Answer (score -2):

I'm more fluent in Sql Server than MySql, having got a solution working in Sql Server the real challenge was converting to a working MySql version!

See if this meets your needs. It works for your sample data, you may of course need to tweak if it doesn't fully represent your real world data.

```
with w as (
  select *, case when animals like '%' || refcol1 || '%' then locate(refcol1,animals) end pos
  from t1
  join lateral (select * from t2)t2 on 1=1
)
select farms, group_concat(refcol2 order by pos separator ',') as Animals
from w
where pos>0
group by farms
order by farms
```

Working [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=538479ae3f2b59774503a3c7d3cdcb98)

Comment: This is slick, but it will require MySQL 8+

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=592c200fbf8ebb0739aa9c4dbb205765 demonstrates a flaw in this approach, though it is possible to fix

Comment: @ysth Thanks, yes that does show with words-within-words a bit more work needed for this particular solution - like I said above it might be the case the OP's sample data doesn't fully represent his actual data, or it might - I'm sure he can clarify. Love it that Emus grunt.